# File.ReadAllText won't thoroughly search entire folder of files unless in debug mode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-debugging

C# novice here, and before you read below, I believe that potentially the single most important piece of information may be the fact that I am searching a shared folder on the network on a remote machine but that still wouldn't answer my question why debug mode works fine.  The filepath to the shared folder is in a textbox on the form and looks like this:

```
\\MachineName\jobFolder
```

So onto my question:

I have a folder full of excel files that myself and others need to search on occasion using a windows form with 1 to 5 conditions with each "condition" simply being a different text string to narrow searches.  I've only shown 1 text string condition below since the rest are duplicates and I didn't want to paste a wall of code if I could help it.

I know there are better ways to search .xls files but I don't need anything fancy, just a raw text search.  Also I know windows search can do this too, but this is a piece of a form that does other functions.

The problem, and the thing that confuses me is that it works fine in debug mode, but only makes it through about the first 1/5 of the files or so among 5,000 total files when running the executable normally, any ideas why?  It doesn't get an error, it just completes as if all went as planned.  Here is the code:

```
string[] words = textBox1.Text.ToUpper().Split(',');
if (words.Length == 1)
{
    foreach (string FileStr in Directory.GetFiles(textBox2.Text, "*.xls" ))
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if ((File.ReadAllText(FileStr).ToUpper().IndexOf(words[0]) >= 0))
                {
                    Action action = () => listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(FileStr));
                    listBox1.Invoke(action);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my worker completed if it is relevant:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        button2.Enabled = true;
        searchButton.Enabled = true;
        searchButton.Text = "Search";
        button4.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        searchButton.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
        textBox1.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        button2.Enabled = true;
        searchButton.Enabled = true;
        searchButton.Text = "Search";
        button4.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        searchButton.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        MessageBox.Show("canceled.", "Canceled");
        textBox1.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        button2.Enabled = true;
        searchButton.Enabled = true;
        searchButton.Text = "Search";
        button4.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        searchButton.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        MessageBox.Show("Search Complete", "Complete");
        textBox1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening excel files and reading them as plain text.  Whatever `words` you are using to search through this text is going to barely function at best.  Excel file formatting differs depending on which version of Excel you are running.  `xls` are [saved as binary files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615597%28v=office.14%29.aspx).  The newer `xlsx` files have a higher level of readability as they are xml based.  You simply cannot read out plain text and not except a high level of nonsense:

`System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FileStr)`//where FileStr is an excel file

You should switch over to the applicable version of [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx) to obtain accurate results.   VSTO is an API that allows you to read excel spreadsheets programmatically using C#.

Comment: I agree, but if you open an excel file in notepad, you can see that a lot of the text is visible, if not all of it.  It just has horrible formatting. We are just looking for keywords.  Such as if it had a certain product name or employee name.  We would then open the excel file that matched it, or use the excel file name to compile data to use.  Trust me it works perfectly for what we need it for, and works in debug mode, but otherwise for whatever reason it stops searching all the files at some point.  For example if 5000 of the files contained John Smith, only debug would find them all.

Comment: @Saintjah When you say "only works in debug mode" do you mean when running the debugger or debug build?

Comment: in debugger my apologies

Comment: Have you tested functionality in a debug build vs a release build?  They both fail as described?  In other words, the code only works if you are directly running the debugger right?  Do you use any preprocessor directives or otherwise have variables setup that influence the behavior of the debugger?

Comment: yes, the debug executable and actual build both fail, whereas the debug mode completes.

Comment: Ok, well if it only works in the debugger then it sounds like  race condition.  It could be caused by the winform closing before the `backgroundWorker` has a chance to complete.  I would typically expect to see that type of failure in a Console application, however if you setup an Exit routine or the user quits out then that would explain it.